# How to find the path of your current working directory?

Tags: shell

How can you find what the is the path of the current working directory?

Comment: `echo $PWD` should work too.

Answer (score 7):

With the command `pwd`. But note that this does not resolve any links that might be in your path, for that you need `pwd -P`.

```
mkdir abc
ln -s abc def
cd def
pwd    # should give a path ending in "def"
pwd -P # should give a path ending in "abc"
```

The paths from `pwd` and `pwd -P` up to the final component will be different as well if there are links in any of the path's components.

Comment: The `/full/path/to` (in the comments)  is only the same for both invocations if none of the components are links

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out grebneke edited this (without my approval) and it seems the reviewers were not paying attention.